# Creating masked overlay spotlight effect to reveal image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create an awesome "reveal" effect on my portfolio page.

Here is an example of what I am trying to visually accomplish with JS and CSS. My example was made using Photoshop.

[image]

**Here is a** **[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ga2D2/109/)** I found and modified where I get sort of close.. But the spot light is too "hard" and not nearly as elegant as what I had in mind. I want it to feel more like a "glow" instead of a circle.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Any help would be much appreciated. I am open to any suggestions for achieving the effect.

```
// Create the spotlight
function createSpotlight() {
    $('.spotlight').width(spotlightDiameter + 'px')
                   .height(spotlightDiameter + 'px');

    for (var i = 0; i < numSpotlightLayers; i++) {
        var layerDiameter = spotlightDiameter + (i * spotlightLayerThickness * 2);
        var opacity = 1 - (i / numSpotlightLayers);

        $('.spotlight').append('<div class="layer' + i + '"></div>');

        $('.spotlight .layer' + i)
                .width(layerDiameter + 'px')
                .height(layerDiameter + 'px')
                .css({borderRadius: (layerDiameter >> 1) + 'px',
                      opacity: opacity,
                      zIndex: (numSpotlightLayers - i)});
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol im so impatient i keep refreshing the page hahaha. God I need a life

Comment: Ooo what if i just created a png image that was faded/transparent in the middle. Add a giant box shadow to each side to fill out the page height and width 100% and set it to follow the mouse. And than i can put both that and the whale image in a negative z-index. 

Thoughts? or is there a better way?

Comment: You can do that with a `radial-gradient()` background. Start it at transparent and fade it to the background color.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient

Comment: oooo duh... Why didnt I think of that? hahah ill give it a try

Comment: @KYSSE, you have the answer in your own snippet. Check the var `spotlightLayerThickness`...

Comment: @AmauryHanser Yes but when i try to manipulate those settings it looks very poor. You can see each level of light instead of a smooth transition of blurred edges. If you know how to manipulate it so it appears somewhat similar to my animated gif example. Please add an answer for me with your example. Id appreciate it so much!

Comment: @KYSSE This is a matter of number of colors available between the light color and the dark color, you could add a bit of noise to the background to make it a bit smoother.

Comment: Thanks @Skyline3000 your idea worked flawlessly https://jsfiddle.net/d4em31n2/16/

Answer (score 2):

So I am going to answer my own question. Shout out and thanks to @Skyline3000 for suggesting the solution in the comment section.

The solution is to create a large div with a radial gradient containing a transparent center. Than you script that div to follow the mouse cursor. Set both the radial gradient div element and the content box "body" to a negative `z-index` value as to not obstruct page content. You also need to set the div to "Fixed" in the JS as to not create scroll bars when the mouse is near view port edges.

Here is a working fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/d4em31n2/16/

Required CSS:

```
  position:fixed;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle cover, rgba(117, 245, 71, 0), rgba(0, 20, 42,1) 4%);
    background:         radial-gradient(center center, circle cover, rgba(117, 245, 71, 0), rgba(0, 20, 42,1) 100%) 4%);
```

Required JS:

```
var img=$('div');
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        var positionLeft = e.clientX - img.width()/2;
        var positionTop = e.clientY - img.height()/2;
        img.css({'position': 'fixed', 'left': positionLeft, 'top': positionTop});
        mousePositionValueDiv.text(e.clientX+', '+e.clientY);
    });
});
```